# simplifyfing a lot of ifs for numbers range folder check

Tags: java, numbers, range

i have a folder structure that i need to open the folders based on the in the given number like this:

Folder:

```
-1000
--1000
--1001
--1002
--1003..
--1250

-1251
--1251
--1252
--1253
--1254
...
--1500

-1501
--1501
and go on, for each 250 files, create a new folder LastNumber+1
```

is there a way to make it simple i just know doing it by this:

```
int typedNumber = 1501;

if(typedNumber > 1000 && typedNumber < 1250) {
OpenFolder(1000)
}
if(typedNumber > 1251 && typedNumber < 1500) {
OpenFolder(1251)
}
if(typedNumber > 1501 && typedNumber < 1700) {
OpenFolder(1501)
}
```

why if will not be a way, cuz i have more than 15000 files, so 15000/250 = 60 IFS

is this possible? like

```
someMethodToGetTypedNumberRange(int number) {
//something do know where folder range the number is in
}
```

obs: cant do the File.. to search cuz it take ages

i appreciate tutorial or any direction

Comment: Look into the modulus operator: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/273783-the-use-of-the-modulo-operator/

Comment: So all your folder numbers have a "1", except the first one "1000"?

Comment: yess!! just the first one that have 0 instead of 1

Comment: What kind of problem forces you to have such enormous and strange tree on your file system? Maybe you can use in memory caching tools or database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simple division and multiplication will do ya.  This code :

```
  int typedNumber = 770;
  int folderNum = typedNumber / 250 * 250 + 1;
  System.out.println( folderNum );
```

Prints "751" for the input value 770.  Is that what you wanted?

EDIT: since you updated your OP, check the list of numbers below and the code too, see if it's correct for what you want.

```
  public static int folderNumber( int fileNumber ) {
      int folderNum = (fileNumber-1) / 250 * 250;
      if( folderNum > 1000 ) folderNum++;
      if( folderNum < 1000 ) folderNum = 1000;
      return folderNum;
  }

  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
      for( int i = 1000; i < 3000; i += 250 ) {
         System.out.println( (i-1) + " -> " + folderNumber( i-1 ) );
         System.out.println( i + " -> " + folderNumber( i ) );
         System.out.println( (i+1) + " -> " + folderNumber( i+1 ) );

      }
   }
```

Produces output:

```
999 -> 1000
1000 -> 1000
1001 -> 1000
1249 -> 1000
1250 -> 1000
1251 -> 1251
1499 -> 1251
1500 -> 1251
1501 -> 1501
1749 -> 1501
1750 -> 1501
1751 -> 1751
1999 -> 1751
2000 -> 1751
2001 -> 2001
2249 -> 2001
2250 -> 2001
2251 -> 2251
2499 -> 2251
2500 -> 2251
2501 -> 2501
2749 -> 2501
2750 -> 2501
2751 -> 2751
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: yes, almost, but try this using the number 1000, 2000, 3000, the correct folder for number 1000, is in the folder 1000 and not 1001!! the code is almost perfectly i just dont know what change i need to make... or i have to threat it using ifs? if its a full number(1200,100, 200)

thanks

Comment: Please clarify your question then.  At what point do you stop adding the "1"?  You have only shown examples with 501, 751 and 1001, and you say "lastnumber + 1" with no other qualification.

Comment: look my first code block, it start in the 1000, 501, 751, its just  example, i will fix it in the op